TypeError: Do not know how to serialize a BigInt in event listener response
I am trying to convert the response I have obtained into the event subscription. I get an object but when I want to transform it I get an error. Is there any function in web3js that transforms BigInt values?
            console.log('logsSupscription data: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
            TypeError: Do not know how to serialize a BigInt


You might need to parse the event logs using the contract ABI. This answer might be helpful.

If you could provide more details, then I can provide a more targeted answer as per your use-case.

I finally solve the issue with the decodelog(). Thx for the suggestion

        const logsSupscription = await web3WWS.eth.subscribe('logs', {
        address: contractAddress,
    });

    logsSupscription.on('data', (data) => {
        const decodedLog = web3WWS.eth.abi.decodeLog(
            ABI.find(e => e.type === 'event' && e.name == 'EventName').inputs,
            data.data,
            data.topics.slice(1)

        );
        console.log("EventName Event: ", decodedLog);

